# redirect request when authentication failed in Kubernetes ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Can I redirect the request to some custom url when kubernetes ingress controller authentication failed with url specified in `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url` annotations?

example

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd
  creationTimestamp: 2016-10-03T13:50:35Z
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770975/how-to-perform-custom-authentication-with-kubernetes-ingress

Comment: Hi, I found the the docs that are responsible for external auth: [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication). Could you please tell which `nginx-ingress` version are you running?

Comment: @DawidKruk I am just using the latest version of Kubernetes ingress controller

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement to:

> redirect the request to some custom url when kubernetes ingress controller authentication failed

can be addressed by using a following annotation:

- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://SOME_URL/`

---

#### Explanation

Assuming that you have an `Ingress` manifest (only the part of it):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local:80/basic-auth/user/password
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://SOME_URL/
spec:
  <-- REDACTED -->
```

I've tested a setup like this and it will work as following:

- You will be first redirected to internal `Service` (`httpbin`) by `auth-url` annotation, where you will be prompted for credentials.
- If you fail above authentication step, you will be redirected to the `auth-signin` URL which for **example** could be: `https://github.com/login` (this is only an example, and not the actual login configuration).

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: User guide: Nginx configuration: Annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/)*
- *[Httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org/)*